# Space constrained asymmetric signature

Tags: digital-signature, public-key-encryption

I need to sign a small string with an asymmetric key encryption scheme.
The signature will be stored on a small chip together with the signed string. I have very little space to spare (about 60bytes for signature + string), so the generated signature should be as small as possible.
I looked around for how to do it, and what I found is that I could use RSA-SHA1, but the generated signature with a 512 bit key is 64 bytes. That is a bit much.
What secure algorithm could I use to generate a small asymmetric signature?
Would it still be secure if I store the SHA1 sum of the RSA-SHA1 signature, and later verify that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're bumping up against here is one of the properties of a [good hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Cryptographic_hash_algorithms) - the return value should be long to protect against [birthday attacks](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirthdayAttack.html) (where two different inputs result in the same output hash). Generally 128-512 bits is preferred hence the SHA-1 signature gives you 512 bits.

As with all things in cryptography security is a trade off. As you are using asymmetric signing have you considered using [RSA-MD5](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DSig-label/RSA-MD5-1_0) as your signature option? This will give you a far shorter return of 128 bits but this comes with the caveat that MD5 is considered broken and is generally being moved away from.